# Loading joblib ML model and exporting with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, joblib

I am creating a small CV Screening GUI and would like to test it with my non-tech coworkers. I am looking to send them a GUI.exe file for them to test my ML model. On jupyter notebook, the module is running smoothly using Tkinter. Running the python file works great and the joblib algo works as needed.

When I want to export the GUI file without joblib, also works great however obviously without any ouput as it doesn't have any predict algorithm. Once I load the model using

```
algo = joblib.load('model.joblib')
```

And try to export using

```
pyinstaller.exe –-onedir  firstprogram.py
```

The file exports however runs into an error that says "Could not load joblib file" and the file doesn't open.

I've seen lots of people facing this issue but none seem to have it solved. Any ideas on how to do this? Or maybe a different method than pyinstaller that would incorporate joblib in the .exe file?